# Socket.io not running from client browser

Tags: node.js, iis, socket.io

I am going to host node.js app on server.
I can access http://domainname:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js on server but not at any client browser.
anyone know where i'm going wrong?

Thanks in Advance!
Nikunj

Comment: What are you getting back from the server? Does the server have a firewall?

Comment: Just time out with no response, and no separate firewall is there, its just in built firewall and its active.

Comment: Post some code. We need to see the `<script>` tag where you load the client script. We also should see the server-side code where you configure socket.io to listen on your server.